# Text of Data Values Out of Position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've managed to append text to this visual thanks to some help on here. But the problem is that it now doesn't correspond to the correct nodes that represent the data.

Instead, the values are in the top left hand corner of the page, rather than the top left hand side of the rectangles. I've attached the code and image for clarity.

Cheers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Partition Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetPack.css">
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="1200" height="720">
    <g></g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  var data = {
    "name": "England",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "North England",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Bradford City",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Mental Health",
                "value": 10.22,
              },
              {
                "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
                "value": 70.23,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
          "name": "Leeds",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.31,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 83.94,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Liverpool",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.56,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 88.34,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Manchester",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.41,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 83.52,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Sheffield",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.24,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 81.16,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "South England",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Brighton",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.77,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 71.34,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Bristol",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.16,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 73.17,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Luton",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.04,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 85.66,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Milton Keynes",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 9.93,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 79.26,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Southampton",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Mental Health",
              "value": 10.37,
            },
            {
              "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
              "value": 79.24,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

  // Max values (for opacity control)
  var maxValues = {
    "Mental Health": 10.77,
    "Alcohol Consumption": 88.34,
  }

  // Creates partion layout
  var partitionLayout = d3.partition()
    .size([1000, 600])
    .padding(2);

  // Returns content/values from dataset (by summing the hierarchy)
  var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)
    rootNode.sum(function(d) {
      return d.value;
  });

  // Applies the returned values to the layout (combines them)
  partitionLayout(rootNode);

  const Colors = ["England", "North England", "South England", "Bradford City",
                  "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Sheffield", "Brighton",
                  "Bristol", "Luton", "Milton Keynes", "Southampton",
                  "Mental Health", "Alcohol Consumption"];

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(Colors)
    .range(["#e6e6ea", "#C06C84", "#C06C84", "#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D",
            "#474747", "#F67280", "#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747",
            "#F67280", "#355C7D", "#547980"]);

  /* The partion layout adds x0, x1, y0 and y1 properties and adds
     a rectangle for each dataum (data point) and uses x & y for
     it's position in the hierachy (descendants) */

  var nodes = d3.select("svg g")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(rootNode.descendants())
   .enter()


      nodes
        .append('rect')
          .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x0; })
          .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y0; })
          .attr('width', function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
          .attr('height', function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
          .attr("opacity", function(d) { return d.value / maxValues[d.data.name] })
          .attr("fill", function(d) {
             var result = null;

             if (Colors.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
               result = color(d.data.name);
             } else {
               result = "white"
             }

             return result;
           });

      nodes
       .append("text")
           .attr("dx", 10)
           .attr("dy", 8)
           .data(rootNode.descendants())
           .text(function(d) {
             return d.data.value;
           });

  </script>
</body>
```

[The outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SuoG.png)

Comment: I believe the svg `text` element only accepts `x` and `y` attributes, not the "dx" and "dy" you are using -- have you tried just changing those atts to "x" and "y"? The coordinates should be relative to origin of the containing node.

Comment: I've tried that, it still remains in the same position

Comment: If you open the dev console (F12) and look at the text elements, are all the values of the text x & y attributes the same? You could always use a function like you did for the rect elements with an offset:
`.attr('x', function(d) { return d.x0 + 10; })`

Comment: Can you share that as answer? That worked perfectly! I need to mark it as  correct so you get some credit!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using relative dx/dy values for your text, you will need to specify absolute x/y values. You can use the same function as you did for the `rect` elements, but add your offsets, like so:

```
  nodes
   .append("text")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0 + 10; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return d.x0 + 8; })
     .data(rootNode.descendants())
       .text(function(d) {
         return d.data.value;
       });
```